# How do I set different colors for these buttons in UIAlertActionController?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

So I have an instance of `UIAlertController` and I want to set different colors for each button text.I know how to set it to every button at once but not to each individually. Does anybody know how to do this? My code is bellow. Thanks!!

```
 func presentAlertController(){
    let alertControl = UIAlertController()
    let sendMessage = UIAlertAction(title: "Send Message", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        print("Send Message")
        self.sendTextMessage()
    })
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        print("Cancel ")
    })
    alertControl.addAction(sendMessage)
    alertControl.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertControl.view.tintColor = UIColor(red: 8/256.0, green: 148/256.0, blue: 148/256.0, alpha: 1)
    self.presentViewController(alertControl, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
        alertControl.view.tintColor = UIColor(red: 8/256.0, green: 148/256.0, blue: 148/256.0, alpha: 1)
    })
}
```

Comment: You can go to the `MainStoryBoard` and just change the background color of the `textfield` for each button.

Comment: @FrancescStudio There is nothing connected to storyboard though. How would I do this for the specific controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That´s possible to do if you´re using the native `UIAlertController`.

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/)

You either need to built your own or you can choose an existing custom one. Examples below:

- [Custom iOS7 AlertView](https://github.com/kwent/ios-custom-alertview)
- [SimpleAlert](https://github.com/KyoheiG3/SimpleAlert)

Comment: Yeah All I want to do is change the text for each button. Like one would be green the other purple.

Comment: Sorry I wrote wrong, you can´t even change the `textColor`. The Apple documentation says "The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.".

Comment: My code above changes the text color to green and I am able to change it to whatever other color I choose. I just can't set them to two different colors?

Comment: Let me check and get back to you.

Comment: @JohnCarp, unfortunately that´s not possible to do. You can as you have done change the views tintColor after it has been presented, but that´s all. Check the quote I have added in my answer.

Comment: @ Rashwan L I can't believe theres no way to do it. It would make things look so much better. any work arounds? Thanks!

Comment: The workaround is to either create a new one or use an existing framework. Check the links in my answer that I added for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to set a different color to each alerviewcontroller buttons.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)


        let button1 = UIAlertAction(title: "button1", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { action in

            print("Button1 pressed")

        })


        let button2 = UIAlertAction(title: "button2", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { action in

            print("Button2 pressed")


        })

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)

            button1.setValue(UIColor.orange, forKey: "titleTextColor")
            button2.setValue(UIColor.green, forKey: "titleTextColor")
            cancelAction.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "titleTextColor")
        }

        alert.addAction(button1)
        alert.addAction(button2)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```